# Directing Water away from Foundation – Regrading

Tags: foundation, waterproofing, drainage, french-drain

What is the best way to build up soil to regrade to direct water away from the foundation wall?  Water is leaking into the crawlspace in the corner behind that tree on the photo.
[image]

We're on a hill so the front of the house is higher, which means all the water currently flows towards the foundation.  I'm currently trying to address that, doing some regrading, digging out a swale/rain garden in the front yard, and building a French drain. But I'm not sure what to do in that corner as it's where most of the water accumulates every time it rains.

The ideal solution would be to extend the French drain along the side of the house under the concrete pathway – but then I'd have to rip out and redo the concrete and that's currently out of budget – maybe sometime in the future.

For now, I want to direct the water away to the right, which means behind the tree and around the foundation to a French drain on that side that I'm currently building.

But for that to work, I have to build up the soil a few inches first, because otherwise the beginning of the French drain in the corner ... and unfortunately water doesn't flow uphill :)

So first, I'm going to dig out a bit more and get my contractor to repair some cracks in the foundation wall there (see next picture).

[image]

But then I'll need to build up the soil again before doing the French drain – otherwise the water will still accumulate there and find its way into the foundation. I measured everything, and for it to have enough slope, the French drain will need to start just under the concrete pathway. So that will still leave about 2 or 3 inches unaccounted for.
So how do I build them up?
Should I just use some clay heavy soil and really try to compact it as best I can with a pounder and then hope the French drain will do the rest?
Any advice greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: That tree  is _much_ too close to the house.

Comment: Can you alter your downspout to dump the gutter water directly into the French drain? I imagine that's already on your list of tasks.

Comment: Weed barrier plus some kind of rock over the top would shed water too. You could alternatively use water feature detailing (EPDM sheet with underlayment and rock over top). If you're in a region where landscape supply places sell clay by the yard, then I'd go with clay.

Comment: Is the tree at the front of the house or the rear of the house?

Comment: @popham Yes. Once the foundation is figured out, the downspout will get a rain barrel and the overflow from the rain barrel will be directed through a pipe parallel to the French drain into the same rain garden  (the rain garden is part of the city requirements for drought friendly landscaping – to create a watershed-type landscape and keep the water from running off)

Comment: @keshlam Yes, the tree is certainly too close – but it would break my heart to cut it down.  It's well established, and the roots go deep so, it hasn't caused any problems in the foundation  (I had a foundation inspection last year – they said if I take care of the water issue, everything else is fine)

Comment: you want to redirect water to the right? that looks to be up hill - I'm assuming the window sill is approximately level along it length as is traditional.

Comment: I'd think about filling the hole adjacent to the wall with bentonite and just filling with clayey soil over top of that.  Then add some regular soil and grade so that the surface is at least an inch above the sidewalk and drains away from the house.

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica Front of the house (hence me wanting to keep it) – the concrete path along the side leads down to the backyard.

Comment: @Jasen yes and no – the way it is currently it would be indeed going uphill but that's what I'm trying to change.  Digging deeper to the right of the tree and around and building up the soil in the corner.  The French drain would then start just below surface and have enough slope to direct the water away and out into the front yard.